# Windows - findstr in for loop (file content)

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, findstr

I have a text file which containts stuff like

```
M       test123
S       test
M       abc
```

and so on...

I'm trying to write a batch script that will do the following:

Read this text file, search every line for "M       " (with spaces!) and then save the found line in a variable, delete the "M       " and store the output in a seperate output.txt

So the output.txt should containt then following:

```
test123
S       test
abc
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (output_whole_check.txt) DO (
SET var!count!=%%F
findstr /lic:"M       " > nul && (set var!count!=var!count!:~8%) || (echo not found)
SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Or is there some easier way to solve that without any additional stuff installed on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.  It echoes all lines to `output.txt` with "M       " replaced with nothing.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

>output.txt (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN ("output_whole_check.txt") DO (
        set "line=%%I"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line:M       =!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Result:

> test123
>   S       test
>   abc

---

Or if your output_whole_check.txt is very large, it might be faster to loop over the lines using a `for /L` loop.  `for /L` is more efficient than `for /F`.  You just have to get a count of the lines to determine how many iterations to loop.

```js
@echo off & setlocal

rem // get number of lines in the text file
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('find /v /c "" "output_whole_check.txt"') do set /a "count=%%I"

<"output_whole_check.txt" >"output.txt" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%count%) do (
        set /P "line="
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!line:M       =!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

The result is the same output.

Comment: this worked fine for me :-), and what to do if i want to add a second one like the "S......", that i have "m...." and "s....." ?

Comment: Easiest thing would be, immediately below the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line, do `set "line=!line:S       =!"` (where the whitespace there is seven spaces, which StackOverflow isn't being very helpful in displaying).  Or if you want to remove *all* strings where you have a letter followed by seven spaces, change the `echo` line to `echo(!line:*       =!` (again, where `* ` is an asterisk followed by seven spaces).

Comment: ok thanks :-)

one last question left for now...

if one of the lines contains anywhere /test/, then i don´t want to have it in output.txt . how would that work ?

Comment: is this to prevent inserting of the full row containing anywhere /test/ ?

Comment: Ah, I messed that up.  take out the `not`.  Do `if /i "!line!"=="!line:/test/=!" echo(... etc.`  Sorry about that.  It means if `!line!` is the same with and without `/test/` removed, then `echo`.

Comment: i want to use now a directory path like c:/users/test/desktop instead of test123

and copy the string next to it in the same line (e.g test123 test123)
and the second test123 should be something else

so c:/users/test/desktop -> copy that and modify some part of it

txt file:

c:/users/test/desktop f:/programs/test/desktop


i know it is hard to explain what i want to do...